# Flask in docker container only with uwsgi on kubernetes

Tags: flask, kubernetes, uwsgi

I am deploying a Flask app in a docker container with Kubernetes. I am using uwsgi to serve it. Most documentation shows deploying Flask using a WSGI server and NGINX when I look it up, but is it necessary? Can I just use uWSGI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *need* an nginx proxy in front of a flask application, but there are some benefits. If you have control over the k8s cluster, I would recommend using an nginx ingress and have it route the traffic to the service that the flask app is running in, then if you have more services its trivial to add them to the nginx config of the ingress.